# Test angular directive with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, ng-html2js

I am trying to test my Angular directive with Karma+Jasmine. So as my directive has `templateUrl` I need caching the template with [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor).
My *karma.conf.js* file:

```
...
files: [
  ...
  'static/views/**/*.html', // to match my directive template
  ...
],

preprocessors: {
  '/static/views/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js]  // to catch the filename as specified in templateUrl 
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  moduleName: 'templates'
}
...
```

And my jasmine spec:

```
describe('Directive unittesting', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  var $compile, $scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  }));

  it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    var element = $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($scope);
    expect(element.html()).toContain("text to contain");
  });

});
```

But seems that for some reasons it cannot inject my `templates` module: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$compile(...`. How to correctly get those things work together?

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem was solved with altering the configuration

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  prependPrefix: '/',
  moduleName: 'templates'
},
```

and preprocessor is actually without the leading slash

```
preprocessors: {
  'static/views/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},
```

So, actually in your directive the path to the template should be exactly like this `/statics/views/directives/my-directive.html`.
And the other thing: do not forget to include `$scope.$digest();` to directive to be rendered with all the context.